# How do i get a value of select box in blueimp using php?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

```
<select name="select1">
<option>
Demo1
</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
<option>
Demo1
</option>
</select>
```

i have two select boxes, i want send the values to the uploadhandler and insert in to database.

**Edit:**

i insert the value from two input fields (its working fine!), but i want to fetch the value of select box.

Jquery for the form data:

```
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {

        data.context = $('<button class="btn btn-primary"/><br/><br/>').text('Upload')
            .appendTo($( ".container" ))
            .click(function () {
                data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                data.submit();
            });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<li class="list-group-item"/>').text(file.name).appendTo($( ".container" ));
        });
        data.context.text('Upload finished.');
    }
}).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = {
        'title': $('[name=title\\[\\]]').val(),
        'description': $('[name=description\\[\\]]').val()
        };
    });
});
```

And the input fields.

```
<label class="title">
<span>Title:</span><br>
<input name="title[]" class="form-control">
</label>

<label class="description">
<span>Description:</span><br>
<input name="description[]" class="form-control">
</label>
```

This is how the UploadHandler.php in blueimp inserts data.

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $file->description = $_REQUEST['description'];
}

protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );

    if (empty($file->error)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
            'sisss',
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
            $file->type,
            $file->title,
            $file->description
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: <option value="value">Demo1</option> ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="select1">
<option value="val1">
Demo1
</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
<option value="value2">
Demo1
</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
echo $_POST['select1'];
echo $_POST['select2'];
```

Comment: i want to get this values in the uploadhandler of blueimp jquery file upload manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="x" value="true">
    <select name="select1">
        <option value="value1">
            Demo1
        </option>
     </select>

     <select name="select2">
         <option value="value2">
             Demo1
         </option>
     </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['x'])){
        echo $_POST['select1'];
        echo $_POST['select2'];
    }
?>
```

Basically, when you press the submit button, it checks if the hidden field named "x" is posted. If it is posted, then echo the 2 selection boxes.

Comment: that i get it. but i want the values, and how the uploadhandler will use this value. check this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration